# Dynamic w/ memory pool VS Static

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, malloc, allocation

I've been under the impression that dynamic memory allocation is slower than static memory allocation, I then read about memory pools, but I'm confused

When we compare allocations, we are talking about using malloc vs initializing a variable. But then If one were to allocate a big array with malloc and access it, would we get the same performance as If we allocated it statically? Let's say you had:

```
int i[100];
j = malloc(sizeof(int) * 100);

// Would these two lines yield the same performance?
i[1] = 10;
j[1] = 100;
```

Thank you for reading...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Memory is memory. Once's its allocated, it all behaves the same. Only the allocation is slower.

Comment: But I read that memory on the heap is slower to access than memory on the stack.

Comment: It's all the same memory. It takes longer to allocate from a heap than the stack but once it is allocated memory is memory.